# how do I group, sort and take out the first N in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, dolphindb

I can get the sorted data in the group, and finally take out the first N in DolphinDB.

But how do I group, sort and take out the first N in mysql?

Thank you first.

The DolphinDB code is as follows：

```
sym = `C`MS`MS`MS`IBM`IBM`C`C`C$symbol;
price= 49.6 29.46 29.52 30.02 174.97 175.23 50.76 50.32 51.29;
qty = 2200 1900 2100 3200 6800 5400 1300 2500 8800;
timestamp = [09:34:07,09:36:42,09:36:51,09:36:59,09:32:47,09:35:26,09:34:16,09:34:26,09:38:12];
t1 = table(timestamp, sym, qty, price);
select top 2 * from t1 context by sym csort timestamp;

timestamp sym qty  price 
--------- --- ---- ------
09:34:07  C   2200 49.6  
09:34:16  C   1300 50.76 
09:32:47  IBM 6800 174.97
09:35:26  IBM 5400 175.23
09:36:42  MS  1900 29.46 
09:36:51  MS  2100 29.52
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do? you can group by using `GROUP BY` ,sort by using `ORDER BY` and take out the first N by using `LIMIT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have MySQLv8.0 that supports `ROW_NUMBER()` you can use something like this:

```
 SELECT `timestamp`,sym,qty,price
  FROM
      (
      SELECT 
      `timestamp`,sym,qty,price,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sym ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS ranking
      FROM `table`
      ) t
WHERE ranking<3
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8fY2DJmCCv7kCnEAPBAU3B/0

Comment: I am curious about the performance and execution plan of this sql statement containing a sub query. If MySQL executes the sub query first and then filter rows by  the column 'ranking', the performance might be very bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sym, sum(qty) FROM table_name GROUP BY sym ORDER BY qty LIMIT 5;
```

Where
`GROUP BY` column - groups rows
`ORDER BY` column - orders rows
`LIMIT` number - picks the first number of rows